# How to open a webpage on bottom and auto-scroll to the top so that it shows all the content to the user?

Tags: php, jquery, dreamweaver

I have a very long div container with all the necessary data in it. I want to show all the content to a user who opens it before I let him/her navigate through the page.

To be more precise- I want to make make my website open at the bottom and then automatically scroll to to the top so that it shows a fast overview of all the data.

Any ideas on how to do it?

If I need PHP or Jquery please explain where to put the code, I am new. Thank you!

I tried to do this with anchors, but they just jump to a certain point- that's not what I need.

Comment: This type of thing will probably confuse more people than it will help...

Comment: I suggest you re-evaluate the content and interface to consider user experience... perhaps package up content into an accordion and have it all collapsed so people can see the main concepts of content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This does'nt really sound like a good idea, but it's up to you!

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(window.scrollHeight).animate({scrollTop : 0 } , 1000);
});
```

Comment: Should down-vote for providing an answer which will create such a poor user experience! But you did point that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already start at the bottom of the page.

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to a particular div...Use a plugin like [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)